# Confusion with port number in MongoDB used by client connections

Tags: mongodb

When I start MongoDB using `mongod.exe` it displays a message like "waiting for connections on port **27017**", but when I execute `mongo.exe` the log message is "connection accepted from **127.0.0.1:60501**".

Now, when I use PyMongo to connect to the DB I assumed that the port number to be used is "**60501**" since this is the port where the connection was established. Surprisingly I got an error saying "connection refused". I thought there was some problem with my MongoDB installation, config file placement, etc.

When nothing fixed it, I just played around by changing the port number to **27017**, and this actually fixed the problem. Can someone explain how this worked out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is not specific to MongoDB. As part of the TCP/IP client/server protocol, services listen on configured ports (typically with well known defaults like 27017 for `mongod`). Clients connect to a server port and also establish their own [ephemeral/dynamic port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) to use for the duration of a client/server session.

Each active session from the same client IP will use a distinct port on the client. The ephemeral port is logged to identify different client connections as they are established.

The logging in your case might be slightly confusing since you are connecting from localhost (127.0.0.1) where the server is also running, but the correct port to connect to is the `mongod` server port (default: 27017).